# UITextField crash undo keyboard icon

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, swift4.2, undo-redo

Facing this error in iPad app. In textfield keyboard will appear. write any text like "qwertyuio" then copy and paste this text multiple times until limit reached out. Now, press undo from the keyboard application will be crashed. I have tried to search out but unable to find any solution.
Exception:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'"

Code, I am using:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
 replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   if textField.text?.count >= 40 && string != ""{
                
      return false
                
   }
  return true
}
```

Please provide the solution.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging out couple of hours. I found the solution for this one.

```
   var textSize = 0
            
   if range.length == 0 {
      //adding
      textSize = range.location + string.count
   }else{
       //removing from field
       textSize = range.location - range.length
    }
            
    if textSize >= 50 {

       return false

    }else {
       if (string.isEmpty && range.length > 0) {
       textField.text = textField.text!.count > range.length ? String(textField.text!.dropLast(range.length)) : ""
       return false
    }
```

It is working fine now.